# Maximization of sum of two functions

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

Is there any relationship similar to the following.
Let $X$ be the maximum of functions $f_1(x)+f_2(x)$.
Let $X_1$ be a maximum of $f_1(x)$ and let $X_2$ be a maximum of $f_2(x)$.
Is  there any relationship between $X$ and $X_1$ and $X_2$?

For example can we say under what condition will $X$ be in-between $X_1$ and $X_2$, $X_1 \le X \le X_2$.

Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is $X = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ or is $f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ maximized when $x = X$? Similarly, is $X_1 = f_1(x)$ or is $f_1(x)$ maximized when $x = X_1$? Same question applies to $f_2(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\max (f+g) \le \max f + \max g
$$