# Sum of functions, maximum property

Tags: functions

so i came along the following post [Maximization of sum of two functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308558/maximization-of-sum-of-two-functions)

and I would like to know how for any given functions $f(x),g(x)$ we can prove that:

$\max(f+g)<=\max f+ \max g$

I do have a small hint about triangle inequality but i am not sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that by definition

- $f \le \max(f)$
- $g \le \max(g)$

thus adding term by term

$$f+g \le \max f+ \max g \implies \max(f+g) \le \max f+ \max g $$

Answer (score 2):

More generally, $$\sup(f+g)\leq \sup(f)+\sup(g).$$

Indeed, let $A=\sup(f+g), F=\sup(f)$ and $G=\sup(g)$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then, there is $x$ s.t.  $$A-\varepsilon\leq f(x)+g(x)\leq F+G.$$
The claim follow.

Comment: maybe its too much to ask, but i can't find a pair of functions where :
$\max(f+g)=\max g + \max f $. Do you have any in mind? Thanks in advance

Comment: Take $f=g$ ;-) $ $